# Magento 2 youtube video not playing

Tags: magento2, products

I have created an API key using [link][1]

[1]: https://console.developers.google.com and created a new project 
and enable API anfter that save that API in Store > configuration > catalog > Product Video and save it

After that I insert video link to my product using but it is not saving showing error 
**Could not get preview image information. Please check your connection and try again.**

Please help

Comment: Why aren't you using the video link from youtube itself? www.youtube.com?v=...?

Comment: I am trying URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YGDyPAwQz0 but it is showing same error

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just got the issue it's a theming issue. I had copied all the layout xml of catalog layout which is conflicting with Youtube video functionality.

Comment: which layout.xml are you using ? share the folder where the template for this is in

Comment: This isn't helpful or explanatory.

Comment: please share with xml file to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by removing the product.info.media container from my child theme Catalog_product_view.xml layout:

```
<container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
```

My project didn't require any structural changes to the product.info.media section at all but I had copied it across (which was unnecessary) when setting up my child theme layout to overwrite the default Magento one, so removing the container from my layout fixed this.

May require some testing if you need that container to stay in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Youtube ID in stead of the entire url, the Youtube ID is the Id that is displayed in the URL after v=